# `probemod` on Mac OS X prints mysterious hexdump instead of module name

Tags: macos, dtrace

The following works fine for grabbing the function name of every syscall made by some command (here we trace the `date` command):

```bash
sudo dtrace -n 'syscall:::entry { @[probefunc] = count(); }' -c "date"
```

It yields output such as:

```
read_nocancel  13
bsdthread_ctl  15
ioctl          26
```

Now it'd be really nice to know the module name also. So I add `probemod` to my trace, like so:

```bash
sudo dtrace -n 'syscall:::entry { @[probemod, probefunc] = count(); }' -c "date"
```

And it yields this (admittedly funky, but ultimately unhelpful) hexdump:

```
           0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f  0123456789abcdef
       0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
      10: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
      20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
      30: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
      40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
      50: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
      60: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
      70: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
      80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
      90: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
      a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
      b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
      c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
      d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
      e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
      f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
ioctl                                                            30
```

Based on [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5488/gbxwv/index.html#6n7imuq0t): I expected the output to show the module name of the current probe. Indeed, there exists [a tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris/dtrace-tutorial-142317.html) which demonstrates that `probemod` can resolve to a library name such as `libumem.so.1` or `libc.so.1`. Not so on my computer.

I am using Mac OS X Sierra 10.12.3 Beta.

Is this expected behaviour of DTrace, or does Mac OS X's implementation have a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syscall provider does not provide probe modules. If it did, it would not be the module that's initiating (calling) the syscall, it would be the module of the syscall itself. That's why it doesn't make sense and, if it did, it wouldn't be that you want.

To confirm, list the probes and observe the empty "MODULE" column:

```
$ sudo dtrace -l -n 'syscall:::entry'
   ID   PROVIDER            MODULE                          FUNCTION NAME
  156    syscall                                             syscall entry
  158    syscall                                                exit entry
  160    syscall                                                fork entry
  162    syscall                                                read entry
  164    syscall                                               write entry
  .
  .
  .
```

The hex dump you're seeing is basically a buffer full of 256 null bytes, which is how the absent probe module is apparently represented.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `stack()` and/or `ustack()` in your function(s):

```
sudo dtrace -n 'syscall:::entry { @[probefunc, stack(), ustack()] = count(); }' -c "date"
```

**Example output:**

```
ioctl                                             
            kernel`unix_syscall64+0x24a
            kernel`hndl_unix_scall64+0x16

            libsystem_kernel.dylib`__ioctl+0xa
            libdtrace.dylib`dtrace_sleep+0x87
            dtrace`main+0x1d15
            libdyld.dylib`start+0x1
            dtrace`0x5
              1
```

**The `stack()` function**

```
void stack(int nframes)
void stack(void)
```

> The `stack()` action records a kernel stack trace to the directed
>   buffer. The depth of the kernel stack is given by the value given in
>   nframes. If no value is given for nframes, the stack action records a
>   number of stack frames specified by the stackframes option. The

**`ustack()` function**

```
void ustack(int nframes, int strsize)
void ustack(int nframes)
void ustack(void)
```

> The `ustack()` action records a user stack trace to the directed
>   buffer. The depth of the user stack is equal to the value specified in
>   nframes. If there is no value for nframes, the ustack action records a
>   number of stack frames that is specified by the ustackframes option.
>   The `ustack()` action determines the address of the calling frames
>   when the probe fires. The `ustack()` action does not translate the
>   stack frames into symbols until the DTrace consumer processes the
>   `ustack()` action at the user level. If a value for strsize is
>   specified and not zero, the `ustack()` action allocates the specified
>   amount of string space and uses it to perform address-to-symbol
>   translation directly from the kernel.

↳ https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/819-5488/gcfbn.html#gcgfo

Comment: on this computer: `@[probefunc, stack(1), ustack(1)] = count();` gives: "ioctl", "kernel`unix_syscall64+0x24a" and "libsystem_kernel.dylib`__ioctl+0xa" respectively, with some errant line breaks to complicate things. it certainly proves that DTrace can see the probe's module name, but unless there's a way to select the important part out of these strings: this cannot be used as a complete replacement for `probemod`. I remain curious as to _why_ `probemod` behaves differently than expected.

Comment: I think you would need to use a format string (`printf()`) or similar in order to get the output that you want. Where does `probmod` behave differently? From the example you linked it looks pretty much the same, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: in the example I linked, the author uses `@[probemod,probefunc,arg0]= count();`, and `printa("probemod = %s, probefunc = %s size = %d, count = %@d \n",@);`, and gets the following result: `probemod = libumem.so.1 probefunc = malloc size = 2048 count = 6`. in other words: `probemod = libumem.so.1` (which is a far shorter string than is returned by `ustack(1)`… which outputs: some whitespace, a tuple delimited by a tilde, a function name and a pointer of some sort)

Comment: That's for a `malloc` process though, which is different from a `syscall:::entry`; If you look right below that you'll see the output of `ustack()` looking pretty much the same as what I would expect you would be getting. I think there might be some formatting examples [here](http://dtrace.org/guide/chp-fmt.html#chp-fmt) and [here](http://dtrace.org/guide/chp-aggs.html) that might eventually lead you to the result you want, unfortunately I haven't really done much in that aspect.

Comment: I thought your question was more in regards to get the associated library to show. If you want to know how to format it then I'd suggest maybe asking another question specifically about that.